# How to extract text from multiple files

Tags: c#

I have upwards of 200 files that I need to extract a certain sequence of lines from, and write the results in a new csv file.  I am just learning C#, but have experience with other languages far in the past.  I have tried looking up all the individual steps, along with Regex, which I don't understand, but I don't know how to stitch it all together.
Sample text:

> --> SAT1_988_Connection_Verify
>
> > EA0683010A01030F15A40202004E2000
> >
> > E0068300
> >
> > E40683010278053A
>
> >
>
> (S45, 10:38:35 AM)

Algorithm Steps

```
 1) I need to point the program at a directory with the files.
 2) I need the program to search through each file in the directory.
 3) I need to find the lines that starts with "E40", of which there could be multiple or none.  Additionally, this line varies in length.
 4) I need to grab that line, as well as the two before it, which are highlighted in the nested block quote above.
 5) There is always a blank line after the target line.
 6)I need to write those three lines separated by commas in a text document.
```

My code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string path = @"C:\ETT\Test.txt";
        string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        foreach (string s in readText)
        {

        }
    }
  public static string getBetween(string[] strSource, string strKey)
    {
        int Start, End;
      if (strSource.Contains(strKey))
      {
          Start = Array.IndexOf(strSource, strKey) -2;
          End = Array.IndexOf(strSource, strKey) + 1;
          return strSource.Substring(Start, End - Start);
      }
      else
      {
          return "";
      }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need more than some stitching.  The first 2 steps are missing.  Please read [ask] and take the [TOUR]

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this. However just to help you (and because you added comparatively detailed amount of information for a first post, you need to look up the following topics

[`Directory.EnumerateFiles` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns an enumerable collection of file names that match a search
>   pattern in a specified path.

[`File.ReadAllLines` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Opens a text file, reads all lines of the file into a string array,
>   and then closes the file.

[`Enumerable.Where<TSource>` Method (IEnumerable, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

[`String.StartsWith` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Determines whether the beginning of this string instance matches a
>   specified string.

https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

> A library for reading and writing CSV files. Extremely fast, flexible,
>   and easy to use. Supports reading and writing of custom class objects.
>   CSV helper implements RFC 4180. By default, it's very conservative in
>   its writing, but very liberal in its reading. There is a large set of
>   configuration that can be done to change how reading and writing
>   behaves, giving you the ability read/write non-standard files also.

---

The only tricky part will be getting 3 lines before

[`List<T>.IndexOf` Method (T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> Searches for the specified object and returns the zero-based index of
>   the first occurrence within the entire List.

From that index, you can use `List[Index-1]` `List[Index-2]` to get the preceding lines

Good luck.